# Using the Concat expression with a join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to append the names of a number of fields with certain criteria.

This works fine:

```
select * from course
left join courseterm on course.courseID = CourseTerm.courseID
where courseterm.termID like 1 or 2
and course.expires not like '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

This also works fine:

```
UPDATE course SET course.Title = CONCAT(`Title`, ' ');
```

However, this tells me that I have an error in my syntax:

```
update course
set course.title = CONCAT('2015/2016-',`Title`)
left join courseterm on course.courseID = CourseTerm.courseID
where courseterm.termID like 1 or 2
and course.expires not like '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set clause must be after the table and join

```
update course
left join courseterm on course.courseID = CourseTerm.courseID
set course.title = CONCAT('2015/2016-',`Title`)
where courseterm.termID like 1 or  courseterm.termID=2 
and course.expires not like '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I changed the where clause a little: update course
left join courseterm on course.courseID = CourseTerm.courseID
set course.title = CONCAT('2015/2016-',`Title`)
where courseterm.termID = 1 or courseterm.termID=2
and course.expires not like '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

Comment: I have update the answer  .. so if the anwer  provided .. resolve you question if fair mark it as aceppeted ..

Answer (score 0):

This `where` clause:

```
where ( (courseterm.termID like 1) or
        (2 and course.expires not like '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
      )
```

"2" is an integer that is evaluated as "true", so that is ignored.

You have three major problems with this `where` clause:

- Do not use `like` for numbers and strings.
- Use parentheses for boolean expressions.
- Use `in` for multiple equality comparisons on the same field.

So, write the logic correctly as:

```
where (courseterm.termID in (1, 2)
       course.expires <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
      )
```

And this should fix your subsequent problems.